# Modify std::less on a shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

This is what I have:

```
struct Foo {
  int index;
}
std::set<std::shared_ptr<Foo>> bar;
```

I want to order `bar`'s elements by their indices instead of by the default `std::less<std::shared_ptr<T>>` function, which relates the pointers.

<strike>I read I can type `std::set<std::shared_ptr<Foo>, std::owner_less<std::shared_ptr<Foo>>> bar`, but I'd prefer to stick to the previous syntax.</strike>

I tried defining `std::less<std::shared_ptr<Foo>>`, but it's not actually being used by the `set` functions. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: Why do you not like the canonical solution to your problem? If you use the shorter syntax, someone will read the code in the future and *completely not realize* that it uses a different ordering mechanism.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to compare by their indices, you'll have to write a comparator that checks by their indices. `std::less<>` will do the wrong thing (since it won't know about `index`) and `std::owner_less<>` will do the wrong thing (since it still won't compare the `Foo`s, but rather has to do with ownership semantics of them).

You have to write:

```
struct SharedFooComparator {
    bool operator()(const std::shared_ptr<Foo>& lhs,
                    const std::shared_ptr<Foo>& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs->index < rhs->index;
    }
};
```

and use it:

```
std::set<std::shared_ptr<Foo>, SharedFooComparator> bar;
```

---

You could additionally generalize this to a generic comparator for shared_ptr's:

```
struct SharedComparator {
    template <typename T>
    bool operator()(const std::shared_ptr<T>& lhs,
                    const std::shared_ptr<T>& rhs) const
    {
        return (*lhs) < (*rhs);
    }
};
```

and then simply make `Foo` comparable.

Answer (score -1):

You can provide your own specialization of `less<shared_ptr<Foo>>` in the `std` namespace.

```
namespace std
{
   template<>
   class less<shared_ptr<Foo>>
   {
   public:      
      bool operator()(const shared_ptr<Event>& a, const shared_ptr<Event>& b)
      {
         // Compare *a and *b in some way
      }
   };
}
```

Then you can form a `set<shared_ptr<Foo>>` without a comparator. I needed this for a `priority_queue<shared_ptr<Foo>>`, where I didn't want to use a `priority_queue<Foo*, vector<Foo*>, int (*)(const Foo*, const Foo*)>`. I am not proud of it, but it works.